# Is there a way to create the contents of a table dynamically using a ajax get request and returned json data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am very new to Javascript. I am supposed to create a table that fills it contents dynamically after submitting "product data" (like: image, brand, model, screensize, os) by using a form.

I've tried everything and nothing seems to work.

I've managed to create a functioning submit button that loads the data of every submitted item to a database on a webserver.

Is there a way to send a AJAX GET request to retrieve this data? It should return JSON data so I can put that data in the table.

Right now my AJAX GET request is not retrieving anything.

Sorry for the disfunctional code:

```
    <table id="table1" border="1">


        <tr>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable(0)">Brand</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable(1)">Model</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable(2)">Screensize</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable(3)">OS</th>

        </tr>
       <tr></tr>
       <tr></tr>
       <tr></tr>
       <tr>
        <form action="<some url>" method="post" id="myForm">

            <td><label for="Image">Upload picture:</label>
            <input type="url" name="image" placeholder="Image" required id="Image"></td>
            <td><label for="Brand">Enter brand</label>
            <input type="text" name="brand" placeholder="Brand" required id="Brand"></td>
            <td><label for="Model">Enter model:</label>
            <input type="text" name="model" placeholder="Model" required id="Model"></td>
            <td><label for="Screensize">Enter screensize</label>
            <input type="number" name="screensize" placeholder="Screensize" required id="Screensize"> 
           </td>
            <td><label for="OS">Enter OS</label>
            <input type="text" name="os" placeholder="OS" required id="OS"></td>


        </tr>

    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<form action="https:url/reset" method="get">



<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").reset();

}
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Reset form">


</form>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Request data</button>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("myForm").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "myForm_get.asp", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's impossible for us to debug your web service. What HTTP response code do you get? Beyond that you'd need to post details of the web service (i.e. the PHP script).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The short answer is Yes, it is possible to create a table based on data returned by an AJAX call. Members of SO generally offer suggestions to your current code. So you need to make some attempts first. It would be good to take the Tour to find out more: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following jQuery example.

```js
$(function() {
  function loadDoc2Arr(dataSource, params) {
    if (params == undefined) {
      params = {};
    }
    var results = [];
    $.get(dataSource, params, function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(i, v) {
        results.push(v);
      });
    });
    return results;
  }

  function resetForm(tObj) {
    var formData = loadDoc2Arr("myForm_get.asp");
    if (formData.length) {
      $.each(formData, function(index, value) {
        $("input", tObj).eq(index).val(value);
      });
    } else {
      console.log("Form Data was empty, sorry.");
    }
  }

  $("#req-data").click(function() {
    resetForm($(this).closest("form"));
  });

  $("#reset-form").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("form")[0].reset();
  });
});
```

```css
input[type='submit'] {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.button-bar {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="<some url>" method="post" id="myForm">
  <table id="table1" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(0)">Brand</th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(1)">Model</th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(2)">Screensize</th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(3)">OS</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><label for="Image">Upload picture:</label>
          <input type="url" name="image" placeholder="Image" required id="Image"></td>
        <td><label for="Brand">Enter brand</label>
          <input type="text" name="brand" placeholder="Brand" required id="Brand"></td>
        <td><label for="Model">Enter model:</label>
          <input type="text" name="model" placeholder="Model" required id="Model"></td>
        <td><label for="Screensize">Enter screensize</label>
          <input type="number" name="screensize" placeholder="Screensize" required id="Screensize">
        </td>
        <td><label for="OS">Enter OS</label>
          <input type="text" name="os" placeholder="OS" required id="OS">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="button-bar">
    <input id="submit-form" type="submit" value="Submit" default /> <input id="reset-form" type="button" value="Reset form" /> <button id="req-data" type="button">Request data</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

This snippet assumes that `myForm_get.asp` will return some amount of data, I would suggest JSON. For example:

```
[
  "https://i.imgur.com/P1nh9JZ.jpeg",
  "Canadian Syrup",
  "CS-1867",
  "42",
  "Windows 95"
];
```

If it's providing some other details, please update your question with an example of the data that is returned.